# Dual divs on the same place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm updating my website to something like this: [axelboberg.se/en/beta_web](http://axelboberg.se/en/beta_web) And in the contact slide down I also want an about me div. ( When I click on About me the "slide down div" will slide down and show the about me section. And when I click on contact the contact section will be showed...) How can I make this? I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and hopefully this can be solved with a simple line of code...

--Update--
Thanks but I mean inside of the div that enters from the top, and only show about or contact at the time... Like minimalmokey did... http://minimalmonkey.com

I want the two parallel divs inside of the "slidenav" div. 
It's too much code to post, see the source code of the website instead..

Comment: "hopefully this can be solved with a simple line of code..." Probably not

Comment: @metareviewr I object!  I think I have solved it in one line (more or less).

Comment: @user1477388 Don't encourage him!!

Comment: @metareviewr Why on Earth not!?

Comment: @user1477388 Cause he is a beginner and next time he runs into problems, he'll think "this can be solved with a simple line of code"

Comment: @metareviewr Sometimes it can, sometimes it can't.  It's good to be less verbose; while not sacrificing code readability.

Comment: PLease provide some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are refering to a smooth scrolling effect. Use jQuery, here is my example code

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/NmrbP/13/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

**Edited**

You can `hide` and `show` using jQuery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/raS55/

```
$('.About').click(function(){
    $('#About').show();
    $('#Contact').hide();
})
$('.Contact').click(function(){
    $('#Contact').show();
    $('#About').hide();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the two divs on the same place but only show one of them at one time, and the other one when I click the button for it to be shown..

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! But could I do it with some sort of fading? Sorry for bad english...

Comment: You can, in my jquery example change .hide() to .fadeOut() and change  .show() to  .fadeIn()

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on About me the "slide down div" will slide down and show the about me section. And when I click on contact the contact section will be showed...) How can I make this, and I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and hopefully this can be solved with a simple line of code...

Actually, this can be done with a simple line of code!

Change your "About me" link to this:

```
<a href="#AboutMe">About Me</a>
```

And, create a `div` like this:

```
<div id="AboutMe">This is about me!</div>
```

When you click the link, your browser will scroll to the AboutMe `div`.

JsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NmrbP/11/

Comment: I tried to fiddle it.. it is not working for me.. have a look at it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/NmrbP/10/).

Comment: @Mr_Green See my edit.  I changed `name` to `id`.  I remembered it was `id` but I looked at resources which say it is `name`.  Apparently, `id` is the one to use, though.